# Flow reports an error on optional object type property that is set?

Tags: reactjs

I have defined a Flow type for my config as (the important parts):

```
interface currentUserType {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  user_image?: string,
  // ... 
}

export interface configType {
  // ...
  user: currentUserType,
}
// ...
```

Field user_image is defined as optional, it might not be there, but if it's there it should be a string. However when I try to pass in the object that has the user_image set to a string:

```
user: {
    id: 123,
    name: "whatever",
    user_image: "b0e7a75302bc1ee854891309ce936804.jpg",
}
```

Flow reports the error: `"Cannot create`App`element because string [1] is incompatible with undefined [2] in property`config.user.user_image`. "`

[1] and [2] here are the references to the above 2 blocks of code. Flow is the latest version 0.86.

I don't get this error, it makes no sense. Isn't the idea behind the optional object type property that it's OK to pass a string, or not pass the property at all?

So if I'm passing the string why does it expect undefined?

I first thought it's the issue with this interface syntax, but it's not complaining about other fields that are not optional. Is this a bug in Flow or I'm being stupid about something here?

UPDATE: as requested, here's the code for App (TLDR: user_image is not used anywhere)

```
// redux store, rootReducer and other stuff is already imported

type Props = {
    config: configType,
};

class App extends Component<Props> {

  config: this.props.config;

  render() {
   return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="app">
          <SomeOtherComponent />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
}
```

UPDATE2: I've added an example on Flow's try repl site: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AEoCmAhgMb6TaxqgBE2pFdA3MigHa5HaTlGgyAV2yMuAVQDOPACoBPDAIDeiUKA4k0RAFyhJubJwDmAGlWgh07AH10JI0QD8u-YY6nEAX3ZcefMgJksByQKEbyiqAqapY8usKiRBJWEURm3oi4CgIACtQYkqAAvFGqQSFh8cGh4dmgXsjl+qBocgDC1cWlMVa60WrqmjqgAOQA6gAWJNwAbjwjZgMWVrZo9sMjAEYk2AB0AFYYRgvm3t5q5pdN+ABisLBdABRK5TWeoLp5sAUAlMUAfKBHuYADwAExQM3+5gGNwA8nCBqDgBCoYgfmxENdQABBDAYJ5-IqA-pqRi4EQcIEwgYASBBdwerzCRSUrQ6IXewGhSwxDUQRAAHlg8KAwUQ+EJoPg8RgWEA

Comment: can you please also add the code that how you are using this user object?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `App` requires presence of `user.user_image`, so flow expects you to [refine the maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/#refining-maybe-types-). So you need to check if `user_image` is not null or undefined i.e. (just wrap `user_image` into `if` statement):

```
   if (config.user.user_image) {
      return <App config={config} />
   }
```

Comment: I've updated the code in question, please have a look. The user_image is not used anywhere yet, so there's no reason for it to complain really.
Also, I've tried your suggestion to wrap it all in if() check, but it still gives the same error. The only way to get rid of the error is to remove user_image completely from the config. It seems like Flow forces it to be undefined even though it's defined as maybe? I also found on their github a few issues with exactly the same error, it seems to be related to the nested interface definitions of types - it breaks the optional properties evaluation.

Comment: @ivanhoe,  strange, but it works well with `type currentUserType`, instead of `interface`

Comment: yeah, it seems to be a bug with nested interfaces. Problem is that I don't know how to import the definitions into another script if I use `type`, that's why I used the `interface`.

Comment: @ivanhoe [it's quite easy](https://flow.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types/), just apply `type` keyword. `export type currentUserType` and `import type { currentUserType } from 'path'`